# .docx problems with SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, docx, sharepoint-workflow

So I have a document library with date, alert and alert-date fields.

The date and alert fields are completed when a doc is uploaded, and there is a workflow which takes the alert away from the date (and also takes an extra day off) and sets it as the alert-date. E.g. If the date is 15/07/2013, and the alert is 1 month, the workflow sets the alert-date to 14/06/013 (15/07/2013 - 1 month and a day). The alerts have options of 1 month, 3 months, 6 months or 1 year. A extra day is always taken off as these workflows are triggered by information management policy which only allows conditions of +1 day (the day is taken away via the workflow and then added via information management policy).

The problem comes when a .docx file is uploaded, as all the alert-dates (even if they relating date and alert aren't populated) are set to 01/01/1900.

I know SharePoint workflows pretty well and have never come across this problem before, so was just wandering if anyone else has and knows a solutions?

Thanks,

Josh.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

The alert-date fields didn't seem to be set at the same time that the workflow was looking them up (for docx files). So I added a minute pause at the beginning of the workflow which gave enough time for all the dates to be set and then for the workflow to look them up, and there are now no issues.

Thanks,

Josh.